# requestLocationUpdates() in separate Thread

Tags: android, location, android-location

I need `requestLocationUpdates()` to be in a separate Thread, in order to not have it blocking the rest of my application (it will run most of the time). What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 28):

When you call `requestLocationUpdates()` this just indicates that you want to be called back when the user's location changes. This call doesn't take a significant amount of time and can be made on the main thread.

When the user's location changes (and based on the criteria you pass to `requestLocationUpdates()`) your listener will be called back via `onLocationChanged()` or notified via `Intent` (depending on which parameters you pass to `requestLocationUpdates()`). If you do a lot of processing in `onLocationChanged()` then you shouldn't run this method on the main thread, but you should just start a background thread (or post a `Runnable` to a background thread and do your work on the background thread.

Another option is to start a `HandlerThread` and provide the `Looper` from the `HandlerThread` as a parameter to `requestLocationUpdates()`. In that case, the callbacks to `onLocationChanged()` will be made on the `HandlerThread`. This looks something like this:

```
    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyHandlerThread");
    handlerThread.start();
    // Now get the Looper from the HandlerThread
    // NOTE: This call will block until the HandlerThread gets control and initializes its Looper
    Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
    // Request location updates to be called back on the HandlerThread
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, listener, looper);
```

Comment: I lost over a week trying to find a solution and you sir saved me. I can't thank you enough.