# Location Listener in doInBackground() of Async Task

Tags: android

Is it possible to get continuous location updates in the `doInBackground()` method of an Async Task?

For example `requestLocationUpdates()` in  `onPreExecute()` and then doing something with the location changes inside the `donInBackground()` method by altering the `onLocationChanged()` method of the listener passed as a parameter for the `requestLocationUpdates()` method.

How can something like this be achieved?

Comment: That wouldn't work.  You only need to call `requestLocationUpdates()` once.  Depending on what you set for time intervals and min distance, you will get `onLocationChanged()` callbacks at some frequency until you call `removeUpdates()`.

Comment: @DanielNugent So there is no way to get location changes in `doInBackground()` by overwritting the listener once it has been declared in  `requestLocationUpdates()` ?

Comment: The AsyncTask class is for doing things on a background thread, and there is nothing here that needs to be on a background thread.  Calling `requestLocationUpdates()` already gives you continuous location updates, just by calling the method.  Take a look here for more explanation, and a solution for processing the `onLocationChanged()` events in a background thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219144/requestlocationupdates-in-separate-thread